# How to show tier price in Magento 2 catalog listing page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, tiered-pricing

Tier price is working fine on the product page, but when we try to show on the listing page then it's not working.

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo ($block->getShowDetailedPrice() !== false)
                        ? __(
                            'Buy %1 for %2 each and <strong class="benefit">save<span class="percent tier-%3">&nbsp;%4</span>%</strong>',
                            $price['price_qty'],
                            $priceAmountBlock,
                            $index,
                            $tierPriceModel->getSavePercent($price['price'])
                        )
                        : __('Buy %1 for %2 each', $price['price_qty'], $priceAmountBlock);
                ?>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Magento shows tier prices only on **Product Details** pages, To show tier prices on **category pages**, Please add below code to your **list.phtml** file

```
if($_product->getTierPrice()){
    $tierPrice = $_product->getTierPrice();
    foreach ($tierPrice as $key => $value) {
        $qty = (int)$value['price_qty'];
        $price = $value['price'];
        $formattedTierPrice = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($price, 2), true, false);
        $savePercentage = ceil(100 - ( (100 / $_product->getPrice())* $value['price']) ) ."%";
        echo "Buy $qty for ".$formattedTierPrice." each and save ".$savePercentage."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: how we can apply this code ? it will not work

Comment: i have tried its not working

Comment: I have added this code and its working fine for me, Check this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/qph7j6

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: i have applied this code below of list file its not working my category page is not loading

Comment: I have added just under the <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?> :   http://prntscr.com/qphpm0

Comment: where we can place this code below of list file can you describe?

Comment: now working thank you soo much @kishor thummar

Comment: Please accept my answer and upvote if this answer is helpful to you.

Comment: can we show tier price with tax on listing page

Comment: Check this https://gielberkers.com/get-product-price-including-excluding-tax-magento-2/

Comment: its not working can you tell me where i can apply this code