# M2 Get Customer Group Price on Category Page

Tags: magento2, catalog, customer-group, tierprice

I seem to be unable to get the current customer group price for a product.

Product is set up with a standard price of £20 and a 'wholesale' group price for 1+ units at £10.

On a category page (when logged in as a wholesale customer), I correctly see the struck through price and £10 beside it.

However, I want to show an icon when a customer is getting a special price because of their group.

`$product->getPrice()` returns 20, `$product->getFinalPrice()` returns 20, `$product->getSpecialPrice()` is null.

I'm trying to get the current group customer price (10) in a variable, so I can compare it. Is this possible? If so, what function do I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the group price by below way,

```
$product->getTierPrice()
```

Check this my another answer reference link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/301538/59677

Comment: Thank you - I believed this showed all tier prices, but it only shows the active / current so works exactly as I need.

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it works for you, so this will useful for other community members also.